# Python save line number

Tags: python, csv, logging

I am writing a python script that processes logs. Currently the way it works is that every time I run it, it reads all the logs it has and processes them. That is the least efficient way to do things, so now I want it to run more efficiently.

Since logs are stored as one file per day, my idea was to store the last log that has been processed and at what line number, and when I run the script again to "take it from there" and go to that particular file and that line number and append every new logged data. Problem is, I am unsure how to store the line number and then check it later.

This is how I open the file to read data

```
with open(file_path, "r+", encoding="UTF-8") as reader:
    line_nr = 0
    for row in reader.readlines():
        ...
        line_nr = line_nr + 1
```

Is this the best way, or is there a more efficient way?

An example would be, if I run the script at 13:00, and by then it has 15000 lines, to store that number in a file, and when I run the script again at 15:00, to read that value (15000) and start from there again.

Comment: use enumerate. `for i, row in enumerate(reader.readlines()):` and `i` will be the line number (starting at 0, so you might want to use i+1)

Comment: Newer logs will have a more recent timestamp than the file with the process lines, right? If so, you could process log files newer than the processed-lines file and append the results.